# Actual business scenrio where we use Prototype scope in spring?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, singleton, prototype

I was readign about differnt scopes for beans in Spring.

Everytime I have created bean in xml , I have never use scope property, which means It was `SingleTon`."

For prototype I read that " Prototype scope is preferred for the stateful beans"

What is meant by stateful beans?
Can someone give me realtime example, where we have prototype scope?

Comment: Might not be the best use case, but we've used them for beans which are dynamically generated by user interaction, of which there could be multiple instances.  For example, subscriptions for notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Since singleton is one instance for the whole application, and this object (I'm speaking about the patter, not even spring yet) if had some state for the example name. This field called name should be fine while just one thread calls the object. BUT singleton is one object for application as I said before.

A typical example in spring

```
@Component
MyComponent{

 private String name;

 public void editName(String newName)
  {
    name=newName
  }

}
```

ASAP more than one thread call this bean, you will have race conditions (you should read about it ). That's why a singleton must not have state but could have other dependencies (dependency injection).

If you use prototype scope, spring will create one object per use, so in the example name will not be shared and there is any race condition, that's fine!!